# How do I test functions with an if statement

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

Hi I need help with some code. I need to test a function but I get a compiler error every time I try to compile. here's what I get, error: comparison between distinct pointer types 'void (*)()' and 'const char*' lacks a cast. 
Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getInput();
bool gameGoing = true;

int main()
{
do{

    cout << "hello world this is a test.\n";
    getInput();
    if(getInput == "false")
    {
        return 0;
    }

}while(gameGoing = true);
}

void getInput()
{
string userInput;
cin >> userInput;
}
```

Comment: Completely unclear what you want to achieve. Your function has no return value, and you are trying to compare a function pointer to a string

Answer (score 0):

Should probably be

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string getInput();
bool gameGoing = true;

int main()
{
    do
    {

        cout << "hello world this is a test.\n";
        if(getInput() == "false")
            return 0;

    } while(gameGoing == true);
}


string getInput()
{
    string userInput;
    cin >> userInput;
    return userInput;
}
```

What I changed:

- added a return type to the `getInput` function, so that the result of it doesn't get dismissed
- fixed the `if` comparison to actually compare the result of `getInput` function againt the `"false"` value
- fixed the while condition to compare the `gameGoing` with `true` value rather than overwriting it

Comment: `while(true == gameGoing)`

Comment: Also `main` should have a `return 0;` after the loop (if for no other reason than good programming practice)

Comment: @UnholySheep: Not required in C++, it will return 0 if no return at the end of the function.

Comment: @init_js `while (gameGoing)`